# ManyToOne ORM association in Doctrine with custom JoinColumn name

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine, model-associations

**Update 01.09.2016** I updated my project: I got rid of custom JoinColumn in my entities (now it's generated one, and my project works w/o errors). And I decided to **shorten the question**:

*Is it good idea to use custom-named JoinColumn in ManyToOne unidirectional association with Symfony 2.7, Doctrine 2.7?*

*My case was:*

---

**Many** *ipGroup entities* (holding many ip addresses) should be associated with **One** *ipGroupPrameters entity*. (see code below)

---

I'm trying to run the code in 3 variants (see 'the Workflow'), and getting different errors:

1). No errors, **but only** filling the *ipGroupParams* DB table, and **not inserting any row** in *ipGroup* table;

2). *"Notice: Undefined index: ipGroupId" in vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Persisters/BasicEntityPersister.php at line 685*

```
$value = $newValId[$targetClass->fieldNames[$targetColumn]];
```

which is really strange - $targetClass **has** ipGroupId in fieldNames (as debugger shows);

3). (in this variant it looks like I change the *owning* side of relation)  *DBAL Exception: An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO ipGroup (ipGroupId, ip) VALUES (?, ?)' with params [null, "134.17.26.129"] ipGroupId cannot be null.*
And this is magic, because I apply setIpGroupId method  on $gObj, and it is updated in RAM (I see it in debugger).

The **Workflow** is:

```
public function createIpGroup()
{
    $this->createParamsObj();
    $gObj = new \Bmw\StatBundle\Entity\ipGroup();
    $gObj->setIpGroupId($this->groupId);
    $gObj->setIp($ip);
    ### 1 variant
    $gObj->setIpGroupParams($this->paramsObj);
    ### 2 variant
    $gObj->setIpGroupParams($this->paramsObj);
    $this->em->persist($gObj); // if not rely on cascade persist
    ### 3 variant
    $this->paramsObj->addIpGroup($gObj);
    $this->em->persist($this->paramsObj);
    ###
    $this->em->flush();
}
public function createParamsObj()
{
    $pObj = new \Bmw\StatBundle\Entity\ipGroupParams();
    $this->groupId = $this->container->get('my.id.generator')->generate();
    $pObj->setIpGroupId($this->groupId);
    $this->em->persist($pObj);
    $this->em->flush();
    $this->paramsObj = $pObj;
}
```

---

Here is initial **entities** code, - then I run *doc:gen:entities* to automatically create getters and setters:

```
/**
 * ipGroup
 *
 * @ORM\Table(
 * uniqueConstraints={
 * @UniqueConstraint(name="ip", columns={"ip"}),
 * @UniqueConstraint(name="userId", columns={"userId"}),
 * },
 * indexes={@Index(name="ipGroupId", columns={"ipGroupId"})},
 * )
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class ipGroup
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="ipGroupId", type="integer")
     */
    private $ipGroupId;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="ipGroupParams", inversedBy="ipGroup")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="ipGroupId", referencedColumnName="ipGroupId")
     */
    private $ipGroupParams;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="ip", type="string", length=45, nullable=true)
     */
    private $ip;
}
```

---

```
/**
 * ipGroupParams
 *
 * @ORM\Table(
 * uniqueConstraints={
 * @UniqueConstraint(name="ipGroupId", columns={"ipGroupId"}),
 * }
 * )
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 */
class ipGroupParams
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;


    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="ipGroup", mappedBy="ipGroupParams", cascade={"persist", "remove"}, orphanRemoval=TRUE)
     */
    private $ipGroup;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="ipGroupId", type="integer")
     */
    private $ipGroupId;
}
```

Comment: Dhumb question : Have you generated the setter and the getter of the entity ?

Comment: Yep, @GeraldChablowski, getters/setters generated code see [link](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1c1V34ekmPbYfDGNAFfRgNVb8Tpvalmo3_dwpNO67NDI/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

Doctrine don't link automatically the two objects, but save them in the same time due to the *persist*. That should work :

```
public function createIpGroup()
{
    $this->createParamsObj();
    $gObj = new \Bmw\StatBundle\Entity\ipGroup();
    $gObj->setIpGroupId($this->groupId);
    $gObj->setIp($ip);
    $gObj->setIpGroupParams($this->paramsObj);

    $this->paramsObj->addIpGroup($gObj);

    $this->em->persist($gObj);
    $this->em->flush();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work - just like **variant2**. Also I suppose, that persisting occurs automatically, due to @OneToMany(..., cascade={"persist", "remove"}, ...) notation in ipGroupParams entity...

Comment: I have edited it and add  $gObj->setIpGroupId($this->groupId);. Should work now.

Comment: Sorry, @GeraldChablowski, but you didn't add any line, you just combined 2 and 3'rd variants

Comment: It's me that I am sorry to not helping you. Because normaly, it should work.